# gcc: error: No such file or directory or fatal error: no input files compilation terminated

Tags: gcc

```
gcc: error: No such file or directory   //or  
gcc:fatal error: no input files 
                 compilation terminated.
```

Facing this gcc error and try to giving the solution of that if you're missing it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. If you are using C programming language make sure there aren't any spaces in your filename. I had spaces in mine and removing them seems to have resolved the issue.

Comment: this does not look like an answer but a comment. please elaborate your answer.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing this error after I came back to my practical programs. Then I searched for it and I'm going to share the solution that may help you to solve this.

Step 1 - First of all do not create a new file directly from vscode or any other code editor you're using.

Step 2 - If you do the above thing, then it can or may cause this error.

Step 3 - So, what you have to do is go to the folder where your all programming files are present. By going to "Open Folder" option in vscode.

Step 4 - Now create the file you want and give it the extension of your desired programming language.

Step 5 - Now you're good to go.

Comment: i like your idea anyway. but here it would be greate if you ask a quesion.